# Attach Annotation to class with JDT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, annotations, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have an IFile with the following content:

```
package com.example;
//@SimpleAnnotation(Blab.ckass)
//@CustomAnnotation(arg1 = Blup.class , arg2 = Blup.Row.class)
public class SimpleClassWithAnnotation {

}
```

How can I add an Annotation(the commented one) to the class? I've tried to use the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537884/how-to-generate-multiple-values-for-a-class-level-annotation-using-jdt) thread, but the source doesn't change. Here is the code snippet, that I used:

```
    final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(this.cu);
    ICompilationUnit cu = JavaCore.createCompilationUnitFrom(this.ifile);
    final CompilationUnit astRoot = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
    final AST ast = astRoot.getAST();
    astRoot.recordModifications();
    final NormalAnnotation newNormalAnnotation = astRoot.getAST().newNormalAnnotation();
    newNormalAnnotation.setTypeName(astRoot.getAST().newName("AnnotationTest"));
```

That's a try to add a simple annotation `@AnnotationTest`. However I need something like this: `@CustomAnnotation(arg1 = Blup.class , arg2 = Blup.Row.class)`

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After alot of tries I got to the solution. The problem was like Unni Kris mentioned is that I have to use `ASTRewriter` in order to manipulate the AST Tree. The other problem was how to save the changes back to the file. I'Ve found a solution, which I'm not sure that is 100% correct, but at least it work for me.

```
    private void addAnnotations(final ICompilationUnit cu) throws MalformedTreeException, BadLocationException, CoreException {

     // parse compilation unit
    final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(cu);
    final CompilationUnit astRoot = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);


    // create a ASTRewrite
    final AST ast = astRoot.getAST();
    final ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ast);



    final ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(astRoot, CompilationUnit.TYPES_PROPERTY);
    final NormalAnnotation eventHandlerAnnotation = astRoot.getAST().newNormalAnnotation();
    eventHandlerAnnotation.setTypeName(astRoot.getAST().newName("CustomAnnotation"));
    eventHandlerAnnotation.values().add(createAnnotationMember(ast, "arg1", "Blup"));
    eventHandlerAnnotation.values().add(createQualifiedAnnotationMember(ast, "arg2", "IsWorkbenchTest", "Blab"));


    final SingleMemberAnnotation runWithFop = astRoot.getAST().newSingleMemberAnnotation();
    runWithFop.setTypeName(astRoot.getAST().newName("SimpleAnnotation"));
    final TypeLiteral newTypeLiteral = astRoot.getAST().newTypeLiteral();
    newTypeLiteral.setType(astRoot.getAST().newSimpleType(astRoot.getAST().newSimpleName("Blop")));
    runWithFop.setValue(newTypeLiteral);
    listRewrite.insertAt(runWithFop, 0, null);
    listRewrite.insertAt(eventHandlerAnnotation, 0, null);
    final TextEdit edits = rewriter.rewriteAST();

    // apply the text edits to the compilation unit
    final Document document = new Document(cu.getSource());
    edits.apply(document);

    // this is the code for adding statements
    cu.getBuffer().setContents(formatFileContent(document.get()));
    cu.save(null, true);
}
protected MemberValuePair createQualifiedAnnotationMember(final AST ast, final String name, final String value, final String value2) {
    final MemberValuePair mV = ast.newMemberValuePair();
    mV.setName(ast.newSimpleName(name));
    final TypeLiteral typeLiteral = ast.newTypeLiteral();
    final QualifiedType newQualifiedName = ast.newQualifiedType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName(value)), ast.newSimpleName(value2));
    typeLiteral.setType(newQualifiedName);
    mV.setValue(typeLiteral);
    return mV;
}

protected MemberValuePair createAnnotationMember(final AST ast, final String name, final String value) {

    final MemberValuePair mV = ast.newMemberValuePair();
    mV.setName(ast.newSimpleName(name));
    final TypeLiteral typeLiteral = ast.newTypeLiteral();
    typeLiteral.setType(ast.newSimpleType(ast.newSimpleName(value)));
    mV.setValue(typeLiteral);
    return mV;
}
```

I've also found a plugin that shows the AST Structure ([ASTView](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/astview/index.php)) of the java files in eclipse. That helped me to figure it out how to create the annotation structure. Just create an java file with the needed structure and see how the AST Structure looks like. Here is the example:

[image: Eclipse Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

The modifications done are only applied to the AST and not recorded onto the Java source code file.

Check the link below. This gives insight on how to write the AST changes to the file.

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html

***Update:***

You can add annotation values like like below:

```
MemberValuePair mV = astRoot.getAST().newMemberValuePair();
mV.setName(astRoot.getAST().newSimpleName("name"));
TypeLiteral typeLiteral = astRoot.getAST().newTypeLiteral();
typeLiteral.setType(astRoot.getAST().newSimpleType(astRoot.getAST().newSimpleName("Blup")));
mV.setValue(typeLiteral);
newNormalAnnotation.values().add(mV);
```

You can then add the NormalAnnotation to the list of modifiers of the Class.

Comment: I have read that and I saw that I have to save it somehow into the file back. I'm not really sure how to attach the Annotation to the class header.

Comment: Thanks, I think i got the idea

Comment: Because the answer was alot more complicated, I'll mark my answer as a solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With your solution using:

```
final ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(astRoot, CompilationUnit.TYPES_PROPERTY);
```

I get one line space between annotation and class. So I tried to add annotation as Modifier and it seems working well. Below is an example how to do it:

```
final MarkerAnnotation javaTaskInfoA = ast.newMarkerAnnotation();
javaTaskInfoA.setTypeName(ast.newSimpleName(JavaTaskInfo.class.getSimpleName()));
acu.accept(new ASTVisitor() { public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
    rewriter.getListRewrite(node, node.getModifiersProperty()).insertAt(javaTaskInfoA, 0, null);
    return false;
}});
```

Marek